# NestedScrollView inside CoordinatorLayout scrolling problem

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

What I want to achieve is that the cardview is also scrolled up, when the recyclerview (In my xml it's just framelayout but I will later replace it) is scrolled. It is easier to understand with the 2 pictures below.

[Not Scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5keSb.png)

[After Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UOxY.png)

As you can see from the second picture, the user profile cardview lingers, while I expect it to be scrolled up.

Another problem is that between toolbar and the cardview, there is an empty space line, which you can see in the first picture. I don't know how to remove that.

And the toolbar is also not showing the title, which is set programmatically. No idea why.

This is the xml file. Thanks in advance!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:statusBarBackground="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/up_ctoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/up_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/up_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/up_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/up_back"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_white" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/up_search"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/up_cardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/up_usericon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/up_username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Username"
                        android:textColor="@color/BlackGray"
                        android:textSize="19sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/up_usericon"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/up_usericon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/up_user_number"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="#10000000"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/up_username"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/up_username" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/up_intro"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:text="Intro: "
                        android:textColor="@color/BlackGray"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/up_user_number"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/up_user_number" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/up_followers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="Followers: 0"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/up_following"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/up_following" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/up_following"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="Following: 0"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/up_intro"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/up_intro" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/up_message"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size_small"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_border_green"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/up_follow"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/up_follow"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mail" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/up_follow"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size_small"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_border_orange"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_follow" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/up_edit"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size_small"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_border_orange"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/up_message"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/up_message"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/up_gender"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_small"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_small"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/up_user_number"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/up_user_number"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/up_user_number"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_male" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/posts_sort_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/up_posts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Posts: 0"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/up_sortby_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_down_blue"
                    android:text="@string/sort_by"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/up_timeline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can add textview as a title inside toolbar in xml

Comment: @ZayniddinMamarasulov But I want that title only to be shown only when the toolbar is collapsed